# JAVA - Solving Bertrand's box paradox

Tags: java, statistics

I am trying to create a block of code to emulate 100000 iterations of the Bertrand's box paradox. Here is the question(taken from Wikipedia):

There are three boxes:

```
a box containing two gold coins,
a box containing two silver coins,
a box containing one gold coin and one silver coin.
```

The 'paradox' is in the probability, after choosing a box at random and withdrawing one coin at random, if that happens to be a gold coin, of the next coin drawn from the same box also being a gold coin.

The answer should be 66%, from the Bayes' theorem.
but my code is returning 58% chance of a second gold coin in the selected box.

here is the code:

```
        double probabilityGold = 0;
        double probabilitySilver = 0;

        Random random = new Random();

        String[][] boxesOfCoins = { { "S", "G" }, { "S", "S" }, { "G", "G" } };

        int matches = 100000;
        while( matches > 0 ) {
            
            int drawBox = random.nextInt( 3 );
            int drawCoin = random.nextInt( 2 );
            String coinDrawn = boxesOfCoins[ drawBox ][ drawCoin ];

            // to ensure that the first coin picked is a gold coin
            while( coinDrawn.equals( "S" ) ) {
                drawBox = random.nextInt( 3 );
                drawCoin = random.nextInt( 2 );
                coinDrawn = boxesOfCoins[ random.nextInt( 3 ) ][ random.nextInt( 2 ) ];
            }

            if( drawCoin == 1 ) {
                String secondCoin = boxesOfCoins[ drawBox ][ 0 ];
                if( secondCoin.equals( "G" ) ) {
                    probabilityGold++;
                } else {
                    probabilitySilver++;
                }
            } else {
                String secondCoin = boxesOfCoins[ drawBox ][ 1 ];
                if( secondCoin.equals( "G" ) ) {
                    probabilityGold++;
                } else {
                    probabilitySilver++;
                }
            }

            matches--;
        }
        
        System.out.println( probabilityGold/100000 );
        System.out.println( probabilitySilver/100000 );
```

My mistake is probably implementing a game of finding a coin, but alas, I can't solve it.
What can i do to get the desired 66% output?

Comment: Note that in your inner while loop, you dont use the calculated values for drawBox drawCoin to pick the coin?

Comment: Yes gyro Gearless, that was my problem. Now it is working as intended. Thank you very much.